# Getting Exception: String could not be parsed as XML when calling SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse this XML (http://numismatics.org/search/apis/getNuds?identifiers=1995.11.282) and pull out the elements under  but when I call SimpleXMLElement I get: **"Exception: String could not be parsed as XML"** (the API is from http://numismatics.org/search/apis)

Here is what the XML basically looks like from the link above:

```
<nuds xmlns="http://nomisma.org/nuds" xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://nomisma.org/nuds http://nomisma.org/nuds.xsd" recordType="physical">

...deleted to shorten question

<digRep>
    <mets:fileSec>
        <mets:fileGrp USE="obverse">
            <mets:file USE="iiif">
                <mets:FLocat LOCYPE="URL" xlink:href="http://images.numismatics.org/collectionimages%2F19501999%2F1995%2F1995.11.282.obv.noscale.jpg"/>
            </mets:file>

...deleted to shorten question

        </mets:fileGrp>
    </mets:fileSec>
</digRep>
</nuds>
```

Here is the test code I'm using from [this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php)

```
$detail = simplexml_load_file("http://numismatics.org/search/apis/getNuds?identifiers=1995.11.282");
$digRep = new \SimpleXMLElement($detail->nuds->digRep); //the slash before the SimpleXMLElement is required for Laravel
$digRep->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://www.loc.gov/METS');
$result = $digRep->xpath('//c:mets:fileSec');

foreach ($result as $title) {
  echo $title . "\n";
}
```

I am wondering if this has to do with "[mets](https://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/):fileSec" but I am not quite sure what "fileSec" is in this context.

Answer (score 0):

`mets` is just the alias for the namespace `http://www.loc.gov/METS/` (the `xmlns:mets` definition). This is perfectly fine XML and it parses in the browser if called directly. I suggest checking if you really can get the XML with PHP (with `file_get_contents()`) and not some error message. Services return sometimes different result for different user agents.